# How to retrieve metadata for return values of an sql server inline table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, metadata, user-defined-functions

It's not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, so where is it?

This is a schemabound inline table valued function, so it doesn't have the issues which a stored procedure might have in being able to vary its output schema(s) based on parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187350.aspx) view if you're using Sql Server 2005 or later

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('udf Name Here')
```